# Compiling PHP IMAP extension in Cygwin: U8T_CANONICAL is missing?

Tags: php, cygwin, php-extension

I have successfully installed Cygwin on my Windows 7 64-bit system.

I have installed and compiled quite a few things without any problems.

- I am seeing an error when compiling PHP 5.4.9 using the `--with-imap and --with-imap-ssl` options.
- I have installed `c-client` in Cygwin and it seems to be installed in `/usr/include/c-client`.
- I then pointed the `./configure` for PHP to that location using `--with-imap=/usr/include/c-client`.

Even when that was done, I get the following error during configuration:

```
configure: error: utf8_mime2text() has new signature, but U8T_CANONICAL is missing. This should not happen. Check config.log for additional information.
```

I couldn't find any further information in regards to Cygwin. Most sources/information for Linux says that this is because c-client is missing, but in my case, I have c-client installed.

Is this because the IMAP extension for PHP is not support on Cygwin? Has anyone successfully compiled the IMAP extension for PHP on Cygwin?

---

Update: Just downloaded c-client from [here](http://www.washington.edu/imap/) in the hopes that if I compile it myself, I will get everything required including `libc-client.a`.

The package looked promising because it contained a build target for Cygwin. However, if I run `make cyg`, I end up with this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h:131,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/bio.h:69,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:61,
                 from osdep.c:210:
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:153: error: parse error before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:199: error: parse error before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:62,
                 from osdep.c:210:
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:199:1: pasting "stack_st_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:62,
                 from osdep.c:210:
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:199: error: parse error before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:210: error: parse error before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:235: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:239: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:243: error: parse error before "X509_REQ_INFO"
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:247: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:254: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:256: error: parse error before "LPCSTR"
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:262: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:281: error: parse error before "X509_CINF"
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:309: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:330: error: parse error before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:453: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:459: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:464: error: parse error before "X509_CRL_INFO"
/usr/include/openssl/x509.h:484: error: parse error before '}' token
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:600,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:62,
                 from osdep.c:210:
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:150: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:152: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:159: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:203: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:204: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:209: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:221: error: parse error before "X509_LOOKUP_METHOD"
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:225: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:253: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:254: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:278: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:407: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:408: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:415: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:416: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:435: error: parse error before "X509_LOOKUP_METHOD"
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:437: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:438: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:443: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:456: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:459: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h:461: error: parse error before '(' token
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:601,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:62,
                 from osdep.c:210:
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:88: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:90: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:95: error: parse error before "PKCS7_ISSUER_AND_SERIAL"
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:104: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:104: error: parse error before "LPCSTR"
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:601,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:62,
                 from osdep.c:210:
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:106:1: pasting "stack_st_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:106: error: parse error before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:112: error: parse error before "PKCS7_ISSUER_AND_SERIAL"
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:116: error: parse error before '}' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:279: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:279: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:279: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:279: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:279: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:281: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293: error: parse error before "LPCSTR"
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: pasting ")" and "_new" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293: error: parse error before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: pasting ")" and "_free" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293: error: parse error before "LPCSTR"
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: pasting "d2i_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: pasting "i2d_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293: error: parse error before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:293:1: pasting ")" and "_it" does not give a valid preprocessing token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:294: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:294: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:294: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:294: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:314: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:316: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:317: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:322: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:323: error: parse error before '(' token
/usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:331: error: parse error before "LPCSTR"

....
```

At this point, I do not know whether the problem is with the openssl headers or libc-client. 
My OpenSSL version is `OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012`.

Any input appreciated.

I tried building without SSL by setting SSLTYPE=none and the build was successful. However, I need SSL support, so am still trying to find a way to build with SSL.

Comment: You might have libc-client installed, but do you have the devel headers as well?  That's the thing that is usually the problem...

Comment: @Charles: Cygwin had `uw-imap-2007-2`, `uw-imap-util-2007-2` and `c-client-2007-2`, which I installed. I couldn't find any packages under `libc-client` or `libc-client-devel`. Interestingly, looking at c-client-2007-2, it contains a `c-client.a` and various headers, but there is no `libc-client.a`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, prefixing libraries with `lib` is a linux thing.  Not so sure about those OpenSSL errors now...